# Computing the irreducible characters of $S_n$ for cycles

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

For n-cycles, Murnaghan–Nakayama gives a very simple computation of the irreducible character $\chi^{\lambda}_{(n)}$. However, computing the value on other pure cycles, even for something as simple as transpositions, seems much more complicated. Is there a nice formula for the character of these special cases?